# Git merge resolve conflicts on symlinks

Tags: git, merge, branch, symlink, conflict

When I merge branch1 to branch2 with strategy set as `-Xours` conflicts are not handled by strategy for softlinks. Merge is failing for softlinks.
Any clue how to handle this scenario?

## steps

```
git checkout branch2
git merge -Xours branch1 -m "syncing branch1"
```

Answer (score 3):

All symbolic-link content changes are treated as "high level" conflicts, without ever involving the "low level" merge code.

As [RomainVALERI answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51261618/1256452), `-X ours` (or `--strategy-option=ours`) is passed to the merge strategy, which in your case is the default `-s recursive`.  But for both recursive and resolve merges, the (eXtended) strategy option "ours" applies only to *conflicts within (ordinary) files*.

Remember that `git merge` works by:

- finding the commit that is the common base point for your current `HEAD` commit, and the other commit you name;
- doing, in effect, two `git diff --find-renames`: one from merge base to `HEAD`, and one from merge base to other commit;
- and then *combining* the two sets of changes, or at least, attempting to.

(Applying the combined changes to the merge base produces the merge result.)

The two `git diff`s can find higher level (tree-level) changes.  For instance, perhaps from merge-base to `HEAD`, you modified `Readme.txt`, but they *removed* `Readme.txt`.  Git cannot combine these, and `-X ours` does not favor your change over theirs: Git just declares a merge conflict anyway.  Similarly, changing a file from "regular file" to "symbolic link" is not handled by `-X ours`.

In your particular example, the "file" (really, blob-content) has not changed modes, it has only changed content: it used to be a symlink pointing to some path *A* and now it is one pointing to some other path *B* on your side, and some third path *C* on their side.  Git *could* resolve this by taking yours per `-X ours`—but it just doesn't.  Git forces you to resolve this conflict manually, just as it forces you to resolve a modified/deleted conflict manually.  No `-X` option will help.

**Edit**: This was declared a bug, and fixed in Git 2.17.  As of Git 2.17, `-X ours` or `-X theirs` selects our or their symlink.  Hence *could* has become *does*, if your Git is 2.17 or later.

Answer (score 0):

-Xours is a strategy option rather than a merge option.

I mean that '-Xours' should modify a strategy, like in

`git merge -s recursive -Xours mybranch`

whereas 'ours' would BE the strategy itself, given as an option to the merge command :

`git merge -s ours mybranch`

However, be careful, as these two processes are different. The latter would just ignore ANY changes in the 'mybranch' branch, not only when there's a conflict.

Comment: `git merge` defaults to `-s recursive` (well, unless you give it more heads to merge, then it defaults to `-s octopus` and `-X ours` becomes inoperative) but this is still the correct reason: `-X ours`, passed to either recursive or resolve strategy, does not affect symlink merging because those strategies are not applied to symbolic link contents.

Comment: @torek Oh you're right, I failed to notice that recursive *is* the default strategy. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer also.

Comment: I need to preserve the changes in branch2. So I cannot use -s ours option.